# How Do I Reference or Pull From A Single Value Parameter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, function

I understand that the parameter in this exercise is holding a value that is a string. I have tried these solutions:

```
function addingGrace(s) {
console.log ("'only the beginning!'");

}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

console.log(addingGrace('only the beginning'), '<-- should be "only the beginning!"');
```

What I do not understand is how to pull the value out of the parameter. All of the tutorials that I have found have multiple parameters.

Here is the original exercise though:

Modify the function to return the given string with an exclamation mark added to the end of it.

```
function addingGrace(s) {

}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

console.log(addingGrace('only the beginning'), '<-- should be "only the beginning!"');
```

Does anyone know where I can find a resource that references this type of work with single value parameters. I do not want the answer to this particular exercise as it is for an entrance exam for a coding school. I really wanted to figure this out myself but I am stuck.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey what's wrong with my question?

Comment: You can click on the "edited x mins ago" link to see what I changed, if you're asking what I changed. If you're talking about the downvote, I didn't vote on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return the parameter `s` which holds the value `only the beginning`.

Please see code snippet.

```js
function addingGrace(s) {
    return s +"!";
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

console.log(addingGrace('only the beginning'), '<-- should be "only the beginning!"');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use backticks (template literals/strings). You also need to `return` from the function:

```js
function addingGrace(s) {
  return `"${s}"`;
}

console.log(addingGrace('only the beginning'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addingGrace(s) {
  return (s + '!')
}

console.log(addingGrace('only the beginning'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
function addingGrace(s) {
  console.log ("'only the beginning!'");
}
```

does not work because the code is already logging your request instead of returning the text you add.

You probaly would want to do is this:

```
function addingGrace(s) {
  return(s);
}
```

But because the exercise wanted the text to have an exclamation point do this:

```
function addingGrace(s) {
  return(s + "!");
}
```

I hope I helped!